# How do Multiboot Operating Systems work

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

I read that the computer loads an OS by searching every attached device's first 512 KB. If that memory space acts as a boot sector , it starts to load the memory space after it.

According to this article : https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html

Multiple OS existing on same hard disk perform "chaining". Now, if all of them are on same hard disk, how does the machine know after how many jumps it's going to find another boot sector.
And what's chaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that the computer loads an OS by searching every attached device's first 512 KB.

The PC BIOS does this - and it doesn't necessarily hit every attached device, just ones it knows how to read and that it is configured to read from settings.

PCs with the newer UEFI standard can load a file directly from an EFI partition on a hard disk.  Traditionally the BIOS doesn't understand file systems such as NTFS or FAT, but UEFI is a bit more intelligent and can actually read files off of a device.

---

In the case of the BIOS, what is loaded is never a full OS but a small program that is a *first stage bootloader*.  This first stage bootloader may load a full OS, but really only in the case of DOS or another very simple OS.

What happens usually is that the first stage bootloader goes on and loads a second stage bootloader, which can be the old NT/XP `NTLDR`, the Windows Vista+ bootloader `winload.exe` or GRUB.

Bootloaders (second stage and above) can do more than the BIOS, so they read a configuration file or data and can present you with a menu of which OS to boot.  The bootloader is overwritten once the OS is loaded.

*Chaining* is where a bootloader calls another bootloader.  Since Windows only boots with its own bootloader, if you have GRUB installed, what GRUB does to load Windows is it goes ahead and just loads the first stage bootloader that the BIOS would have loaded anyway.  This is stored in the first sector of its partition, I believe.  The same is done with DOS.

It's not required if GRUB can boot the OS directly, which it can for any Linux.  Linux doesn't care too much how itself and its initramdisk get into memory unlike other OSes.

---

UEFI can load an OS directly, but Windows doesn't support this AFAIK, so usually UEFI systems  directly load `winload.exe` and run that instead.

Other non-PC bootloaders like U-Boot (something your home router may run) understand FAT and Linux filesystems and directly load Linux from them, and then start the OS directly.

Comment: So if I install grub into a multiboot system, it will remove the first 512 bits and put itself there ? And how will it get the third stage files from both OS?

Comment: It depends on how you install it. Old linux's could write LILO to the MBR, or could use the old MBR code to load from the active partition and put the LILO code there. Grub is more modern and I do not know its details.

Comment: The first 512 bytes minus the size of the partition table is too small for a full bootloader except for possibly DOS, so GRUB isn't entirely installed there, but a "first stage" bootloader that likely loads something else that eventually ends up loading GRUB.

Answer (score 1):

> I read that the computer loads an OS by searching every attached device's
>   first 512 KB.

Almost correct. PC style hardware read the first sector, which is 512 bytes.
(not kilobytes).

> If that space acts as a boot sector, it starts to load the space after it.

Also almost correct. Classic motherboard firmware contained something called a BIOS. When the PC powered up that would get executed. One of its tasks was to hand control over to another deice (e.g. to a floppy drive).

More advanced versions did not support just a single device, but would check multiple devices and move on to the next one in case one failed to provide a booting solution. E.g. it could try to boot from a floppy, and if that failed move on to trying to boot from a CD, and it that failed try to boot from the first harddisk. (where *first* is also interesting if you have multiple disks).

Most of the time it would read the first sector of a harddisk. And a harddisk typically had a partitioning scheme (MBR for IBM compatible PC) and some boot code. It then would follow a chain of loaders.

E.g. firmware would load a single boot sector and start the code within.

The code read from that sector would understand more about the disk and load a bigger program.  (repeat if needed with more stages).

> Multiple OS existing on same hard disk perform "chaining".

The OS does not perform chaining. But if one of your later stages is an advanced boot-loader program (e.g. grub) then that can ask for user input and depending on that it can continue in different ways. E.g. it could load a linux kernel and it could load & start the NTloader.